# React + SCSS: Unable to use flexbox display-flex

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

**Note:** I am using boostrap css for some other components.

**ISSUE =>**
I want the `text-area` and `image` to be side by side:

> **html :**

```html
<div class="card">

      <div class="card__text">
        <div>
          <h3 class="card__text-title">Leed guitarist</h3>
          <p>Some random lorem ipsum text to see how this thing looks here. 
             It will have around 300 characters...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card__text-buttons">
          <a hef="#">Like</a>
          <a hef="#">Know more</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card__img">
      </div>

    </div>
```

> **scss :**

```
.card {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex !important;   // <<=== WON'T WORK !!
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

  &__img {
    flex: .4;
    min-height: 200px;
     // css properties   
  }

  &__text {
    flex: .6;
    // css properties 
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    &-title {
      font-weight: 800;
    }
    &-buttons {
      display: flex;
      a {
        // css properties 
      }
    }
    h3 {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    p {
      margin-top: 30px;
      font-size: 13px ;
    }
  }
}
```

## Current result

[image]

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. I am frustrated because I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Pretty sure I am missing something really small here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue here https://codepen.io/dpogni/pen/bGedwbZ

You need to add `flex-direction: row;` to your card class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a closing curly brace in scss.

EDIT:

I tried the same on codepen and the image is getting rendered on the right of the text already.
Maybe some other css is overriding it